# How to make a border in only one corner/two sides while using border radius - React Native

Tags: react-native, border, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to make a tab with a curved bottom left corner and a border on the left and bottom sides, but I can only get it to have the border on all sides or none. 
I'll get it on all sides if I use anything like:

```
tab2:{
 top: 3*width/8,
 width: 3*width/16,
 backgroundColor: 'red',
 borderColor:'white',
 height: width/8,
 borderBottomLeftRadius: 100,
 borderWidth: 1,
 borderRightWidth: 0,
 borderTopWidth: 0,
 borderTopColor: 'transparent
 borderRightColor: 'transparent'}
```

And if I take out `borderWidth: 1,` I don't get a border at all.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I just overlapped the View component and created border at top left and bottom right region only
here is the expo demo link:-
https://snack.expo.io/@vivek22719/multiple-screens

here is my code:-

```
   <View style={{width:297,height:128,backgroundColor:"#fff",borderWidth:1,marginTop:20,borderColor:"darkcyan"}}>
   <View style={{width:300,height:130,top:-2,left:-2,backgroundColor:"#fff",borderTopStartRadius:40,borderBottomEndRadius:40,display:"flex",justifyContent:"center",alignItems:"center"}}}}><Text style={{fontSize:24,color:"darkcyan"}}>A space for parents</Text><Text style={{fontSize:24,color:"darkcyan"}}> by parents</Text>
   </View>
   </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned border will be all or none. If you try with single side it will work on `Android` but may not work on `IOS` . You can give a try with `View` by giving proper `height` and `width`. I have managed for bottom border with `View`.

For left and bottom border it would be tough but may be it will work by two `View` element between your main elements design. One for left side and another for bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Define the border for left and bottom part using `borderLeft` and `borderBottom`

```
tab2:{
 top: 3*width/8,
 width: 3*width/16,
 backgroundColor: 'red',
 borderColor:'white',
 height: width/8,
 borderBottomLeftRadius: '100',
 borderLeft: '1',
 borderBottom: '1',

}
```

Comment: have you checked with `IOS`? As per my experience it will not work with `IOS` . check this issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29